# Java. Вывод определенного количества символов

Tags: java

Озадачился тем, что иногда необходимо вывести String определенной длинны.
Нашел в интернете отличное решение

```
public class RandomString { 

    // function to generate a random string of length n 
    static String getAlphaNumericString(int n) 
    { 

        // chose a Character random from this String 
        String AlphaNumericString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                    + "0123456789"
                                    + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"; 

        // create StringBuffer size of AlphaNumericString 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

            // generate a random number between 
            // 0 to AlphaNumericString variable length 
            int index 
                = (int)(AlphaNumericString.length() 
                        * Math.random()); 

            // add Character one by one in end of sb 
            sb.append(AlphaNumericString 
                          .charAt(index)); 
        } 

        return sb.toString(); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        // Get the size n 
        int n = 20; 

        // Get and display the alphanumeric string 
        System.out.println(RandomString 
                               .getAlphaNumericString(n)); 
    } 
}
```

Далее, мне было необходимо вывести только цифры, но опять же, с тем учетом, чтобы я мог задавать количество символов. И я модифицировал это так

```
public class RandomNumber {

    // function to generate a random string of length n
    public static String getAlphaNumber(int n)
    {

        // chose a Character random from this String
        String AlphaNumber = "0123456789";

        // create StringBuffer size of AlphaNumericString
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // generate a random number between
            // 0 to AlphaNumericString variable length
            int index
                    = (int)(AlphaNumber.length()
                    * Math.random());

            // add Character one by one in end of sb
            sb.append(AlphaNumber
                    .charAt(index));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Потом я создал и третий класс, для вывода только букв (опять же главные условие - что можно задать количество букв)

```
public class RandomAlpha {

    // function to generate a random string of length a
    public static String getAlphaString(int a) {

        // chose a Character random from this String
        String AlphaString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";

        // create StringBuffer size of AlphaNumericString
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a);

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

            // generate a random number between
            // 0 to AlphaString variable length
            int index
                    = (int)(AlphaString.length()
                    * Math.random());

            // add Character one by one in end of sb
            sb.append(AlphaString
                    .charAt(index));
      }

            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы это было все в одном классе, я уверен, что есть решение гораздо красивее и разумнее моего, но я новичок и придумать лучшее решение я пока не смог. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вынесите свой формат в отдельные константы и передавайте его параметром.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomString.getStringByFormat(10, RandomString.LETTERS);
        RandomString.getStringByFormat(5, RandomString.NUMBERS);
        RandomString.getStringByFormat(3, RandomString.LETTERS_AND_NUMBERS);
    }
}

class RandomString {

    public static String LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static String NUMBERS = "0123456789";
    public static String LETTERS_AND_NUMBERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            + "0123456789"
            + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";

    static String getStringByFormat(int length, String format){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int index = (int) (format.length() * Math.random());
            sb.append(format.charAt(index));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать, чтобы это было все в одном классе,

Сделать очень просто. Берем все три метода и складываем в один класс:

```
public class MyWonderfulStringClass { // любое имя, какое нравится

    public static String getAlphaString(int a) {
        // тут код
    }

    public static String getAlphaNumber(int n) {
        // тут код
    }

    static String getAlphaNumericString(int n) {
        // тут код
    }
}
```

Comment: но мне кажется что можно короче сделать
или я ошибаюсь...

Comment: А, т.е. надо не в один класс, а в один метод. Конечно, можно. Код идентичный, отличаетася только значением одной строковой переменной. Нужно просто передать в метод параметр, какую их этих трех строк использовать. В соседнем ответе как раз об этом.